# trouble with onclick for making display none and block

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use onclick code and style.display in js to hide a something and make a dive which it's display is none by default to get block and appear.

The first one won't hide and the other one won't appear!

The script file works fine, I have other things in js which work perfectly.

```js
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('chatbutton').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('chatbox').style.display = "block";
  }
```

```html
 <a href="" id="chatbutton" >
  <div class="mychat text-center" onclick="showDiv()">
      <p class="chattext">Chat Support</p>
  </div>
</a>

<div id="chatbox" class="mychat_open text-center d-none">
  <p class="chattext">Chat Support</p>
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Enter your Name...">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Enter your Email...">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.mychat_open{
   width: 15vw;
   height: 20vh;
   background-color: black;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 20px;
   right: 20px;
   color: white;
   opacity: 0.8;
   min-height: 28px; 
}
```

Comment: You've wrapped the text in an `<a href="">` which means a click will run the code, then cause the page to get reloaded. Don't use inline code. Use this instead: `document.getElementById('chatbutton').onclick = function (e) { e.preventDefault(); /* rest of code */ };` (and make sure that script is below the main HTML content)

Comment: In addition, `<a href="">` with an empty href does different things in different browsers. Don't use this in production.

Comment: oh, thank you, removed the href from <a>, now the <a> gets hidden upon clicking but the other <div> won't appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS works fine, but you have the `onclick` function inside an empy `<a href="">` tag. You can either add a `#` to it like this `<a href="#">` or change it to some other kind of element such as a `<button>` to keep the page from reloading when it is clicked.

You should toggle the "d-none" class for the element you want to show instead.

```
document.getElementById('chatbox').classList.remove('d-none')
```

Comment: removed the href from <a>, now the <a> gets hidden upon clicking but the other <div> won't appear

Comment: Need to see the CSS for these classes `mychat_open, text-center d-none`

Comment: edited post and added the mychat_open,
d-none and text-center are bootstrap 4 default codes.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to make the chat box hidden initially, then you can set its display style property to `display:none`.

```
<div id="chatbox" class="mychat_open text-center d-none" style="display:none">
    <p class="chattext">Chat Support</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Enter your Name...">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Enter your Email...">
    </div>
</div>
```

This will hide the chatbox until the user clicks the button. This works because the js changes the `style.display` property of the element with id 'chatbox' to `block`.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a return false to the link to prevent a page reload

added a style rule to actually hide the box initially, so we can show it :)

(added the p to visually show it's the other box showing, not some hiccup.)

```js
function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('chatbutton').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('chatbox').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <a href="" id="chatbutton">
      <div class="mychat text-center" onclick="showDiv(); return false;">
          <p class="chattext">Chat Support</p>
      </div>
  </a>

  <div id="chatbox" class="mychat_open text-center d-none" style="display: none;">
      <p class="chattext">Chat Support Box</p>
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Enter your Name...">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Enter your Email...">
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear May be this will help you in your case

cancel the a string and add button like

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Chat Support</button>
```

Add in your div with ID chatbox  style display none,

```
 <div id="chatbox" class="mychat_open text-center d-none" style=" display: none">
```

then add java

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("chatbox");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
```

}
}

your complete forma like this

```
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Chat Support</button>
<div id="chatbox" class="mychat_open text-center d-none" style=" display: none">
<p class="chattext">Chat Support</p>
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Enter your Name...">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Enter your Email...">
</div>
```

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("chatbox");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
 }
```

}

More details may you can find

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp